# Any graduation plans?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm not too familiar with the beta system of SE. How does it work? I saw on Area51 that this site has been in beta since January 2011 and we have more 'traffic' than some other sites that have graduated. What's the deal?

Comment: There have been questions asked about this before, which aren't recent, but still interesting: [Apr 19, '14](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/1665/2953); [Feb 14, '13](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/1505/2953)

Comment: Well on one side it doesnt really matter if we are in beta or not on the other one i dont like it not to know what it going on 

Comment: Betas have some higher chance to be discontinued, but I don't think that's something to worry about in our case after having existed over three years. Beta also means the privilege thresholds are lower for editing and closing/reopening questions, which is helpful in our case as there aren't so many 2K/3K users yet. There are also other differences, like that elections aren't usually held on betas.

Comment: We are good on all marks except number of questions per day, last 6.2 vs the 10 they are looking for to graduate. But I feel the main issue is that even we haven't fully defined how our site operates (hence my other question), our "fit" with Stackexchange needs to be made completely clear before graduation I would think. 6.2 questions per day is a cutoff that can probably be relaxed in our case; there is definitely a place for a philosophy stack but staying in beta forever just to meet that (relatively) arbitrary requirement would seem silly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Officially, mods do not know anything more than users about graduation plans. The admins control graduation; presumably they will graduate us when they feel we are ready. This will probably be sometime after we really iron out our subjective questions issue ([the issue I posted recently](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2820/subjective-questions-deciding-what-we-want-as-a-community?cb=1)) but before we actually reach the 10 questions per day mark (currently at 6.2 which I think is reasonable for a site like this.

Comment: do you think it is a possibility that someday they will discontinue this site?

Comment: Will humanity someday cease to exist? Whether by the administrative axe or the slow decay of time, one day this site will cease to exist. The important part is that the wisdom we've imparted on others shall live on, passing from one generation to the next, ever imprinted on the human species until such a day when there is no one to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

## Update 2nd June, 2015

A [recent blog post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/205264) gives us some more information about when SE, Inc. considers sites for graduation:

> The TL;DR:
>
> 1. When a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll consider it for graduation.
> 2. If a public beta site does not produce consistently helpful content, and lacks the caretakers needed for flags and spam to get handled and our Be Nice policy to be upheld, it will be closed.

Recently our questions/day has gone down to [4.8](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2578/philosophy), however, it seems to fluctuate around 6 normally.